# unexpected token < bundle js in reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating js app from scratch , and this is my webpack config file

```
import path from 'path';

export default {

  entry: path.join(__dirname,'/client/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname,'client'),
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],

      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  }
}
```

this is my `.babelrc` file :

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

this is my `index.html file` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my `client/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './Component/App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

this is my App component

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  return <h1>Hello from react</h1>;
}
```

this is dependencies used by the app

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

build is success but i got an error `Unexpected token < bundle.js:1` after running the app, 
anyone know what is causing the error? thank

Comment: Please make a [MCVE] of your problem. Without all of the relevant parts of the project, this cannot be reproduced. In particular, we don't know what's in 'client/index.js', which is probably what is corrupting the bundle.

Comment: edited.. @E_net4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add filename to your webpack.config within output:

```
entry: path.join(__dirname,'/client/index.js'),
output: {
  path: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
}
```

basically this is happening because in your index.html you are importing bundle.js

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

but your webpack is outputting index.js, by adding the filename attribute, webpack will now output bundle.js

Comment: i get this error after running, 

```configuration has an unknown property 'filename'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.```

Comment: oh, that's my bad i put it literally under the output, it should be within output object, thank you very much